# How to decode the imap 7bit enoded messages?

Tags: php, imap, encode, gmail-imap

Just i use the below code for 7bit encoded message to decode.It's working for some message but some messages showing encrypted.some message still showing encrypted. How to decode this messages properly? Anyone please help me.

```
   public function decode7Bit($text) {

    // actually base64-encoded, and decode it.      
    if($this->_isEncodedBase64($text)){
        $text = base64_decode($text);
    } 


    // Manually convert common encoded characters into their UTF-8 equivalents.
    $characters = array(
                 '=20' => ' ', // space.
                 '=E2=80=99' => "'", // single quote.
                 '=0A' => "\r\n", // line break.
                 '=A0' => ' ', // non-breaking space.
                 '=C2=A0' => ' ', // non-breaking space.
                 "=\r\n" => '', // joined line.
                 '=E2=80=A6' => '…', // ellipsis.
                 '=E2=80=A2' => '•', // bullet.
    );

    // Loop through the encoded characters and replace any that     are found.
    foreach ($characters as $key => $value) {
        $text = str_replace($key, $value, $text);
    }
    return $text;
   }

   private function _isEncodedBase64($data){

    if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
   }

  $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $messageId, 1.2);
  if (!strlen($body) > 0) {
    $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $messageId, 1);
  }
  // Get the raw headers.
  $raw_header = imap_fetchheader($inbox, $messageId);

  // Get the message body.
  $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $messageId, 1.2);
  if (!strlen($body) > 0) {
    $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $messageId, 1);
  }
 //  print_r($body);
  // Get the message body encoding.

   $encodings = array(
  0 => '7BIT',
  1 => '8BIT',
  2 => 'BINARY',
  3 => 'BASE64',
  4 => 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE',
  5 => 'OTHER',
);
// Get the structure of the message.
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $messageId);
// Return a number or a string, depending on the $numeric value.
if ($numeric) {
  $encoding =$structure->encoding;
} else {
  $encoding= $encodings[$structure->encoding];
}

  // Decode body into plaintext (8bit, 7bit, and binary are exempt).
  if ($encoding == 'BASE64') {
    $body = imap_base64($body);
  }
  elseif ($encoding == 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE') {
    $body = quoted_printable_decode($body);
  }
  elseif ($encoding == '8BIT') {
    $body = quoted_printable_decode(imap_8bit($body));
  }
  elseif ($encoding == '7BIT') {
    $body = $this->decode7Bit($body);
  }
  else{
      $body = $body;
  }
```

Comment: Nothing is encrypted here.   What's a message that you think is being displayed wrong?  7-bit means no encoding was applied.  But perhaps it is actually Quoted Printable or Base64.  Judging from your code, it looks like you've tried to manually do quoted printable encoding. Just use that.